# SOQL subquery access variables

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, compile-error

Attempting to access the variables MIlestone1_Project__c has a Lookup relationship to Account with relationship name: `Projects__r'.

```
List<Account> accList = [
    SELECT Id, Name, EHR_Status__c, PM_Status__c, Project_Imp_Status__c, Other_Status__c, (
        SELECTClient_Advisor_Email__c, Resource_Coordinator_Email__c
        from Projects__r
    ) 
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id IN :AcctIds
];

List<String> emailAdds = new List<String>();
for (Account al: accList) {
    emailAdds.add(al.Client_Advisor_Email__c);
    emailAdds.add(al.Resource_Coordinator_Email__c); 
}
```

I get the error message:

> Variable does not exist: Client_Advisor_Email__c

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to loop through your subquery list of records. Here is how you would access these fields and records:

```
for(Account a : accList)
{
    for(Project__c p : a.Projects__r)
    {
        System.debug(p.Client_Advisor_Email__c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Some background

When working with data that's related to an object, there's two ways it can be related:

- Child-to-Parent (e.g. `Opportunity.Amount` in a query on `OpportunityLineItem`)
- Parent-to-Child (e.g. `(SELECT Id FROM Opportunities)` in the `SELECT` clause in a query on `Account`)

An important concept to keep in mind here is that *all relationship fields in Salesforce are 1:n (one-to-many)*. Given a single relationship field, for example, `OpportunityId` on `OpportunityLineItem`, that field can only hold a single value.
`OpportunityLineItem`, the *child* record, can only be related to a single `Opportunity`, the *parent* record.

If we switch our point of view to the `Opportunity`, a single parent (`Opportunity`) can have multiple children (`OpportunityLineItems`).

### How related data is stored/represented in the query result

In the end, every record we query data for is presented to us as an `SObject`

If your query looks like this:

```
[SELECT Id, Account.Name, (SELECT Id, UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItems) 
FROM Opportunity 
LIMIT 1]
```

Then we're querying data from `Account`, `Opportunity`, and `OpportunityLineItem`. *All* of those are represented as `SObject`. This allows us to do things like `Account myAccount = myOpp.Account;`

### What happens with the parent-to-child subquery results then?

Since a parent can have many children, we can't store *all* of the child records in a single `SObject`.

If Salesforce automatically chose one child to put in an SObject for us, which one would it be? How would we switch to another child record?

I hope that this is starting to make your code-senses tingle. We want a single variable to hold multiple pieces of data. What tool(s) do we have to accomodate that?

Salesforce's solution to this is to return child records as a `List<SObject>`. This allows us to do things like `List<OpportunityLineItem> myOLIs = myOpp.OpportunityLineItems;`

### Now, to your issue

Your code was assuming that the child records were a single `SObject` (glommed onto the `Account` object) instead of being an honest-to-goodness `List<SObject>` of its own.

Some common patterns to work with records from a subquery include:

Looping over the subquery results (the safest method)

```
for(Account a : accList){
         // a.Projects__r is a List, and we're feeding it into a loop
         //   just like we would with any other List
         for(Project__c p : a.Projects__r){
             System.debug(p.Client_Advisor_Email__c);
         }
     }
```

Accessing a single record from the subquery

```
// It's just like accessing an index of any other List because _it is just a List_
for(Account a : accList){
    System.debug(a.Projects__r[0].Client_Advisor_Email__c);
}
```

Salesforce prefers we use the nested loop approach because, after a certain number of child records, there's an internal call to `queryMore()` which a loop can handle correctly (and basically nothing else can handle it properly). Even calling `a.Projects__r.size()` runs the risk of needing a `queryMore()`.

Comment: Bryan Anderson's answer is correct (and much shorter). My goal here was to give a deeper understanding about _why_ his solution works, and why OP's initial approach _didn't_, which wouldn't have worked very well as a comment.

Comment: Great explanation @DerekF